# C# How to stop while loop when enter pressed

Tags: c#, while-loop

I have a homework where I have to make a program that asks numbers for ten times in a loop and in the end gives the sum of those ten numbers.
But it also must be possible to stop the loop and give the sum of numbers when enter is pressed.

I have tried something like this in while loop, but it didn't also work:

if( Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey( true ).Key == ConsoleKey.Enter ) break;

Can anyone suggest solutions?

Thanks in advance!

```
           {
            int i = 0;
            int number;
            string number_s;
            int sum = 0;


            while (i < 10)
            {
                { 
                i++;

                Console.WriteLine("Enter number:"); 
                number_s = Console.ReadLine(); 
                Int32.TryParse(number_s, out number);

                    sum += number;
                }
            }
           Console.Write("Sum is: {0}", sum);
          }
```

Comment: When you press Enter your _number_s_ will be set to an empty string (string.Empty) now you just need to check for that and use the _break_ keyword to exit the loop

Comment: `if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(number_s)) break;`

Comment: Just to explain why your attempt failed: `ReadLine` is blocking. It will wait until there is something and an Enter in the buffer. `KeyAvailable` and `ReadKey` are non-blocking. Thus they will either way encounter empty buffer: before you enter the number or after `ReadLine` emptied the buffer.

Comment: What do you want to do when the user enters "Lilian", or "Banana" instead of a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should work fine.

```
while (i < 10)
{
    i++;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter number:"); 
    number_s = Console.ReadLine(); 
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(number_s))
        break;
    input = Convert.ToInt32(number_s);
    sum += input;
}
Console.WriteLine("The sum of the entered numbers are : {0}", sum);
```

Comment: If the user enters "Harikrishnan" instead of a number, the previous number will get added again. Is that the desired behavior? I think not...

Comment: @ZoharPeled Convert.ToInt will throw an exception in this case. So your behaviour will not happen.

Comment: @Holger yes, that's correct. I think I've misread the answer (question was using `int.TryParse` so I assumed answer was using that too).

Answer (score 1):

When you press Entery Key, the value in **number_s** will be empty.
You just need to use

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(number_s))
 break;
```